# Is there a way to cluster transactions (journals) data using python if a transaction is represented by two or more rows?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning, accounting

In accounting the data set representing the transactions is called a 'general ledger' and takes following form:

[image: Simplified Data Example]

Note that a 'journal' i.e. a transaction consists of two line items. E.g. transaction (Journal Number) 1 has two lines. The receipt of cash and the income. Companies could also have transactions (journals) which can consist of 3 line items or even more.

Will I first need to cleanse the data to only have one line item for each journal? I.e. cleanse the above 8 rows into 4.

Are there any python machine learning algorithms which will allow me to cluster the above data without further manipulation?

The aim of this is to detect anomalies in transactions data. I do not know what anomalies look like so this would need to be unsupervised learning.

Comment: it depends if you already know what an anomalous transaction looks like (supervised learning) or not (unsupervised)

Comment: To clarify I do not know what anomalous transactions look like so this would be unsupervised learning as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Use gaussians on each dimension of the data to determine what is an anomaly. Mean and variance are backed out per dimension, and if the value of a new datapoint on that dimension is below a threshold, it is considered an outlier. This creates one gaussian per dimension. You can use some feature engineering here, rather than just fit gaussians on the raw data.

If features don't look gaussian (plot their histogram), use data transformations like log(x) or sqrt(x) to change them until they look better.

Use anomaly detection if supervised learning is not available, or if you want to find new, previously unseen kind of anomalies (such as the failure of a power plant, or someone acting suspiciously rather than whether someone is male/female)

Error analysis: However, what if p(x), the probability the an example is not an anomaly, is large for all examples? Add another dimension, and hope it helps to show the anomaly. You could create this dimension by combining some of the others.

To fit the gaussian a bit more to the shape of your data, you can make it multivariate. It then takes a matrix mean and variance, and you can vary parameters to change its shape. It will also show feature correlations, if your features are not all independent.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368618/multivariate-gaussian-distribution